# Angular2: EXCEPTION: Attempt to use a dehydrated detector: QuizzPage_2 -> select

Tags: exception, angular, ionic2

I'm having an issue in my ionic2/angular2 app.
I'm building a quizz app, in which the user is prompted to answer questions, on radio choices.
The moment the first choice is made, I get this error:

```
EXCEPTION: Attempt to use a dehydrated detector: QuizzPage_2 -> select
```

The console:[image: EXCEPTION ERROR]

The code breaks here when I debug Pause On Exception:

```
  SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub = function (fn, value) {
        try {
            fn.call(this._context, value);
        }
        catch (err) {
            this.unsubscribe();
            throw err;
```

**Here are my main files:**

The page.html:

```
(...)
<ion-item radio-group  *ngFor="#choice of quizz.getChoices()">
    <ion-label>
      <p courant>{{ choice }}</p>
    </ion-label>
    <ion-radio (click)="onSubmit($event, choice)">
      {{ choice }}
    </ion-radio>
</ion-item>
(...)
```

My page.ts:

```
import {Page, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Quizz} from '../models/quizz';
import {QuizzResultsPage} from './quizz-results.page';
import quizzes from '../../data/quizzes';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/quizz/Quizzes/templates/quizz.page.html',
})

export class QuizzPage {
  nav;
  quizz;

  constructor(nav: NavController, params: NavParams) {
    this.nav = nav;
    // Load the quizz with passed topicId from the params.get (import{NavParams})
    this.quizz = this.loadQuizz(params.get('topicId'));
  }

  loadQuizz(topicId) {
    // cont quizz = data (import quizzes from '../../data/quizzes';)
    const quizz = quizzes.filter((quizz) => {
      return quizz.topicId === topicId;
    })[0];
    return new Quizz(quizz);
  }

  onSubmit(event, answer) {
    this.quizz.submitAnswer(answer);
    if (this.quizz.isCompleted) {
      this.nav.push(QuizzResultsPage, {
        quizz: this.quizz
      });
    }
  }

}
```

I'm still able to finish the quizz, but in the end in my result page, I can't go back or restart the quizz, and my navbar breaks...

My resultpage.html:

```
(...)
<ion-card-content>
      <p>
        Votre score:
        <span primary>{{ quizz.getScore() }}</span> / <b>{{ quizz.getGradingScale() }}</b>
      </p>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>

  <!-- Questions with answers -->
  <div [hidden]="quizz.isPerfect()">
    <ion-card *ngFor="#i of quizz.items" style="background-color:aliceblue;">
      <ion-card-header>
        <b bluegray text-uppercase>Question: </b>
        <p>
          {{ i.question }}
        </p>
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
        <b bluegray text-uppercase>Réponse:</b>
        <p courant text-justify>{{ i.answer }}</p>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
  </div>


  <!-- Exit & Restart -->
  <div padding style="width:70%; margin: 0 auto">
    <button item-right block (click)="onHomeClicked($event)">Recommencer
      <ion-icon name="refresh-circle"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <button itel-left block (click)="onGoHome($event)">Accueil
      <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

And finally my results.ts:

```
import {Page, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import {TopicsPage} from '../../topics';
import {Home} from '../../../home/home';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/quizz/Quizzes/templates/quizz-results.page.html',
})

export class QuizzResultsPage {
  nav;
  quizz;

  constructor(nav: NavController, params: NavParams) {
    this.quizz = params.get('quizz');
    this.nav = nav;
    this.nav.pop();
  }

  onHomeClicked(event) {
    this.nav.setRoot(TopicsPage);
    this.nav.pop(TopicsPage);
  }

  onGoHome(event){
    this.nav.setRoot(Home);
    this.nav.pop(Home);
  }
```

Someone have an idea? Thanks

Comment: Post you `Quizz` class please

Comment: I just found out that I had to change the order setRoot/nav.pop to get rid of the navbar disappearance! And on the other hand, If I set a button submit on each page of the quizz with the EXCEPTION is gone. But that's not the wanted behaviour...